# $1 and multiple groupings

Tags: regex, perl

If I have a regular expression and if I am expecting one or the other terms to match, say

```
ab*cc or ab*dd
```

I have a RegEx like

```
while($line =~ /(ab*cc)|(ab*dd)/g)
{
    # print match whether its abcc or abdd
    # print $1?
}
```

But I am unsure how `$1` will work.
Is there such a thing as `$2` meaning that it will be `$1` if it matches abcc or `$2` if it matches abdd? How can I extend this if I have say 3 groupings or so, meaning it could either be X or Y or Z?

Comment: Yes, there is a `$2`, `$3`, etc. Give it a try! `$1` matches the first opening parenthesis from the left. `$2` matches the second, and so on. See Jonathan Leffler's answer below for an interesting consequence of this.

Comment: You could do `$line =~ /(ab*cc|ab*dd)/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Captured parenthesis are labeled in the order of their appearance.  In an or'ed group like that, either one or the other will match.  To test which matched, simply use `defined`:

```
while($line =~ /(ab*cc)|(ab*dd)/g)
{
    if (defined $1) {
         print "first group matched: $1";
    } elsif (defined $2) {
         print "second group matched: $2";
    }
}
```

If you do not care about distinguishing which group matched, just use a single parenthesis around the entire expression

```
while($line =~ /(ab*cc|ab*dd)/g)
{
    print "Will hold whichever matched: $1";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
while ($line =~ m/((ab*cc)|(ab*dd))/g)
```

Now `$1` will be whichever of the two terms matches, and `$2` will be the same if the first term matches but undefined otherwise, while `$3` will be the same if the second term matches but undefined otherwise.  The extension to three or more terms should be obvious.

---

The `m//` notation is a marginally more explicit notation equivalent to `//`.  Otherwise, it does not alter things.  The `$1` etc values are determined by the order of the open parentheses `(`.  The outer pair wrap everything that's matched; the two inner pairs capture the terms.  Note that if you had `m/((ab*cc)+|(ab*dd)+))/g`, the contents of `$2` or `$3` would be the last of the repeated terms, not the complete set of the repeated terms.

#### Example 1

```
$ cat example2.pl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <>)
{
    chomp $line;
    print "Line: <<$line>>\n";
    while ($line =~ m/((ab*cc)|(ab*dd))/g)
    {
        printf "\$1 = <<%s>>; \$2 = <<%s>>; \$3 = <<%s>>\n",
               $1 // "undef", $2 // "undef", $3 // "undef";
    }
}
$ perl example1.pl
abbccabccaccaddabddabbdddabbbdddd
Line: <<abbccabccaccaddabddabbdddabbbdddd>>
$1 = <<abbcc>>; $2 = <<abbcc>>; $3 = <<undef>>
$1 = <<abcc>>; $2 = <<abcc>>; $3 = <<undef>>
$1 = <<acc>>; $2 = <<acc>>; $3 = <<undef>>
$1 = <<add>>; $2 = <<undef>>; $3 = <<add>>
$1 = <<abdd>>; $2 = <<undef>>; $3 = <<abdd>>
$1 = <<abbdd>>; $2 = <<undef>>; $3 = <<abbdd>>
$1 = <<abbbdd>>; $2 = <<undef>>; $3 = <<abbbdd>>
$
```

#### Example 2

```
$ cat example2.pl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <>)
{
    chomp $line;
    print "Line: <<$line>>\n";
    while ($line =~ m/((ab*cc)+|(ab*dd)+)/g)
    {
        printf "\$1 = <<%s>>; \$2 = <<%s>>; \$3 = <<%s>>\n",
               $1 // "undef", $2 // "undef", $3 // "undef";
    }
}
$ perl example2.pl
abbccabccacc
Line: <<abbccabccacc>>
$1 = <<abbccabccacc>>; $2 = <<acc>>; $3 = <<undef>>
$
```

Comment: I believe his question is even simpler than that. But nice one, though.

Comment: so the "m" seems to force the match to $1? I suppose then i could have m/((ab*cc)|(ab*dd)|(ab*ee)|(ab*ff))/g) and $1 would return any of these 4 matches

edit: nevermind I see what you mean. I see. the nested parantheses

Comment: The `m//` notation is a marginally more explicit notation equivalent to `//`.  Otherwise, it does not alter things.  The `$1` etc values are determined by the order of the open parentheses `(`.  The outer pair wrap everything that's matched; the two inner pairs capture the terms.  Note that if you had `m/((ab*cc)+|(ab*dd)+))/g`, the contents of `$2` or `$3` would be the last of the repeated terms, not the complete set of the repeated terms.